# update_all ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Im trying to update all post where a condition is true. If the condition is true should the field category_id be set to params[:category_id]

Every time im trying to do it will my code update all post where the condition is true and set it to "--- !ruby/hash:ActionController::Parameters categori_id: '169'"

Instead of just 169.

My controller action look like this

```
def update_all_notes
@deletefolder = Categori.find(params[:id])
System.where(:categori_id => params[:id]).update_all(:categori_id => params[:categori_id])
redirect_to :back
end
```

My form look like this:

```
<%= form_tag update_all_notes_path(category.id) do %>
<%= collection_select :kategori_id, :id, @current_company.category.where.not(:name => category.name), :id, :name %>
<button>move</button>
```

this is the parameters i send to the action
"categori_id"=>{"categori_id"=>"169"},
 "id"=>"168"}

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your hash you should replace params[:categori_id] to be params[:categori_id][:categori_id]

as the hash is `{ "categori_id" => {"categori_id" => 169}, "id" => X }`

Answer (score 0):

Example of `update_all` use:

```
ids = [1,2,3]
records = Mammal::Human.where(id: ids)
records.update_all(status: :enlightenment, enlightenment_at: Time.zone.now, enlightenment_by: "myself")
```

I will rather use `status: value` over `:status => value` syntax